# How to register C++ React Native module in Android

Tags: java, android, c++, react-native

I have a C++ React Native module derived from `facebook::xplat::module::CxxModule`. It is working ok with iOS project but now I'm trying to figure out how to use it from Java. The only documentation I found is the comment in React Native codebase stating that:

> NativeModules whose implementation is written in C++ must
>   not provide any Java code (so they can be reused on other platforms),
>   and instead should register themselves using
>   CxxModuleWrapper

My question is how to register C++ module in Java using CxxModuleWrapper

Comment: "Your question really is how to call C++ from javascript without calling java I suspect (if possible)?" - No, I can just use JNI and call any C++ library easily, the problem here is that I will need to do all data conversion and will have to implement all the callbacks and promises to communicate with JS side. This could be avoided using C++ module inherited from `facebook::xplat::module::CxxModule`. I have such a module and I can use it from Objective C but not from Java

Comment: Can you use some tool to generate bindings, [like this](https://github.com/sulewicz/djinni-react-native)

Answer (score 2):

Please check this blog for detail: https://medium.com/@kudochien/how-to-write-a-react-native-cxxmodule-59073259f15d.
Snippet from the blog:

### Export it from native

```
extern "C" HelloCxxModule* createHelloCxxModule() {
  return new HelloCxxModule();
}
```

### Register it in java

```
public final class HelloCxxPackage implements ReactPackage {
  @Override
  public List<NativeModule> createNativeModules(ReactApplicationContext reactContext) {
    return Arrays.<NativeModule>asList(
        // I have librnpackage-hellocxx.so the exported createHelloCxxModule() above.
        CxxModuleWrapper.makeDso("rnpackage-hellocxx", "createHelloCxxModule")
    );
  }
  @Override
  public List<ViewManager> createViewManagers(ReactApplicationContext reactContext) {
    return Collections.emptyList();
  }
}
```